# javascript or PHP sorting array of x,y coordinates

Tags: php, json, sorting

I populated a highcharts graph with json data in the form:
[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]

The data is sorted by x value first, because the file gets an unsorted list of numbers, then counts the number of times the number appears.  This is stored as [number,count].
Its plotted as X,Y to demonstrate our database traffic.

Now, I want to sort so I can see the 10 most frequently requested values in the list.
How can I sort a json object by this Y parameter? Thanks!

Sample data:

```
[[4,1],[20,1],[43,1],[57,4],[59,1],[60,1],[61,1],[66,1],[68,3],[70,3],[72,2],[75,1],[77,3],[80,2],[81,3],[82,1],[83,1],[84,4],[85,5],[86,3],[87,1],[88,5],[90,7],[92,5],[95,2],[97,4],[98,4],[99,1],[100,6],[102,5],[103,3],[104,15],[105,3],[108,3],[109,2],[110,2],[111,2],[112,3],[113,7],[114,8],[115,11],[116,7],[117,15],[118,9],[119,4],[120,16],[121,7],[122,4],[123,6],[124,3],[125,1],[126,7],[127,5],[128,13],[129,5],[130,11],[131,13],[132,15],[133,17],[134,14],[135,11],[136,5],[137,5],[138,9],[139,7],[140,2],[141,1],[142,7],[143,2],[144,4],[145,11],[146,10],[147,9],[148,9],[149,7],[150,6],[151,12],[152,3],[153,9],[154,5],[155,6],[156,5],[157,5],[158,8],[159,10],[160,6],[161,2],[162,3],[163,45],[164,3],[165,8],[166,14],[167,12],[168,3],[169,5],[170,3],[171,8],[172,6],[173,9],[174,8],[175,11],[176,24],[177,23],[178,4],[179,3],[180,3],[181,11],[182,7],[183,7],[184,5],[185,7],[186,15],[187,11],[188,12],[189,9],[190,8],[191,6],[192,7],[193,4],[194,3],[195,12],[196,5],[197,8],[198,6],[199,16],[200,4],[201,14],[202,10],[203,9],[204,12],[205,8],[206,6],[207,6],[208,4],[209,12],[210,6],[211,7],[212,8],[213,12],[214,9],[215,7],[216,3],[217,11],[218,13],[219,9],[220,8],[221,12],[222,8],[223,9],[224,2],[225,5],[226,19],[227,9],[228,7],[229,11],[230,5],[231,3],[232,4],[233,11],[234,8],[235,11],[236,10],[237,5],[238,8],[239,15],[240,13],[241,9],[242,7],[243,7],[244,14]]
```

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom compare function:

```
data.sort(function(a, b){
  return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

Example:

```
var data = [[4,1],[20,1],[66,1],[68,3],[70,3],[72,2],[84,1],[96,4],[102,2]];
data.sort(function(a, b){
  return a[1] - b[1];
});
// data now contains:

   [[4,1],[20,1],[66,1],[84,1],[72,2],[102,2],[68,3],[70,3],[96,4]];
```

If you want to sort in descending order instead just do `b[1] - a[1]` instead.

Comment: Can you help explain this? I have seen this answer before, but it looks to me like it compares 2 variables, not sorts an entire array.

Comment: @user1771824 See the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort The sort function does all the sorting on the array, and it is built in to Javascript. You just have to tell it how to compare two elements and it can sort the whole array.

Comment: @user1771824 If you're sorting strings lexicographically you don't even have to tell it how to compare them. It already knows. Try out: `['orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'blueberry'].sort();`

Comment: Is there a similar solution I can use with PHP?  Because, with the way I build the array, the resolution is lost by the time it reaches javascript.

Comment: @user1771824 You can do the same thing in php using the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function of js

```
var myList = [[1,2], [1,1]];
myLisyt.sort(function(item1, item2) {return item1[1] - item2[1]});
```

result is: `[[1,1], [1,2]]`

Comment: Thanks everybody! This works, I guess I was reading it wrong.  It returns an object that I can iterate through, very good.